# Plot a chirped gaussian pulse with pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I want to draw this gaussian wave packet, with chirped frequency:

[image: gaussian pulse]

This plot was created with [Desmos.com](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/) online tool.

The function that generated this waveform is

[image: equation]

My result with `pgfplots` is the following:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}
\addplot [domain=0:4, samples=1000,line join=round,line cap=round]
{exp(-(x-2)^2)*cos(30*(deg(x)-2)-6.5*(deg(x)-2)^2)};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: pgfplots result]

So I understand that the math engine behind `pgfplots` has some difficulties at evaluating a squared term of `x` inside a cosine function (I tried plotting it without the `-6.5*(deg(x)-2)^2` part, and the result is fine).

How can I overcome this?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think that you are using wrong the `deg`operator. Could be `\addplot [domain=0:4, samples=1000,line join=round,line cap=round] {exp(-(x-2)^2)*cos(deg(30*(x-2)-6.5*(x-2)^2))};` what you need?

Comment: @JuanCastaño Indeed! So it is correct to do `cos(deg( f(x) )` ?

@user241266 Maybe I will later change the quadratic term.

Comment: @tush Using `(\x,{exp(-(\x-2)^2)*cos(deg(30*(\x)-2)-6.5*(\x-2)^2)})` will give the desired output

Comment: @Excelsior All right, thanks a lot! I didn't notice that. Write an answer down below and I will mark this question as "Answered".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by [@Juan Castaño](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/231368/juan-casta%c3%b1o) in the comments, the `deg` command convert the argument to degrees, so there is no need to use it for the quadratic expression.

[image: no chirp v01]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot[
            domain=-1:5, 
            samples=500,
            ]
            (\x,{exp(-(\x-2)^2)*cos(deg(30*(\x)-2)-6.5*(\x-2)^2)});
        \end{axis}
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I personally give `pgfplot` the specific variable (i.e., `\x`), therefore I changed the expression of the function a bit.